# Vagrant multi vm ssh connection setup works on one but not the others

Tags: ssh, ansible, vagrant

I have searched many of the similar issues but can't seem to figure out the one I'm having. I have a Vagrantfile with which I setup 3 VMs. I add a public key to each VM so I can run Ansible against the boxes after `vagrant up` command (I don't want to use the ansible provisioner). I forward all the SSH ports on each box.

I can `vagrant ssh <server_name>` on to each box successfully.

With the following:

```
ssh vagrant@192.168.56.2 -p 2711 -i ~/.ssh/ansible <-- successful connection
ssh vagrant@192.168.56.3 -p 2712 -i ~/.ssh/ansible <-- connection error
ssh: connect to host 192.168.56.3 port 2712: Connection refused
ssh vagrant@192.168.56.4 -p 2713 -i ~/.ssh/ansible <-- connection error
ssh: connect to host 192.168.56.4 port 2713: Connection refused
```

And

```
ssh vagrant@localhost -p 2711 -i ~/.ssh/ansible <-- successful connection
ssh vagrant@localhost -p 2712 -i ~/.ssh/ansible <-- successful connection
ssh vagrant@localhost -p 2713 -i ~/.ssh/ansible <-- successful connection
```

Ansible can connect to the first one (`vagrant@192.168.56.2`) but not the other 2 also. I can't seem to find out why it connects to one and not the others. Any ideas what I could be doing wrong?

The Ansible inventory:

```json
{
  "all": {
      "hosts": {
          "kubemaster": {
              "ansible_host": "192.168.56.2",
              "ansible_user": "vagrant",
              "ansible_ssh_port": 2711
          },
          "kubenode01": {
              "ansible_host": "192.168.56.3",
              "ansible_user": "vagrant",
              "ansible_ssh_port": 2712
          },
          "kubenode02": {
              "ansible_host": "192.168.56.4",
              "ansible_user": "vagrant",
              "ansible_ssh_port": 2713
          }
      },
      "children": {},
      "vars": {}
  }
}
```

The Vagrantfile:

```rb
# Define the number of master and worker nodes
NUM_MASTER_NODE = 1
NUM_WORKER_NODE = 2

PRIV_IP_NW = "192.168.56."
MASTER_IP_START = 1
NODE_IP_START = 2

# Vagrant configuration
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  # The most common configuration options are documented and commented below.
  # For a complete reference, please see the online documentation at
  # https://docs.vagrantup.com.

  # default box
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/jammy64"

  # automatic box update checking.
  config.vm.box_check_update = false

  # Provision master nodes
  (1..NUM_MASTER_NODE).each do |i|
    config.vm.define "kubemaster" do |node|
      # Name shown in the GUI
      node.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
          vb.name = "kubemaster"
          vb.memory = 2048
          vb.cpus = 2
      end
      node.vm.hostname = "kubemaster"
      node.vm.network :private_network, ip: PRIV_IP_NW + "#{MASTER_IP_START + i}"
      node.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 22, host: "#{2710 + i}"
      
      # argo and traefik access
      node.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 8080, host: "#{8080}"
      node.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 9000, host: "#{9000}"

      # synced folder for kubernetes setup yaml
      node.vm.synced_folder "sync_folder", "/vagrant_data", create: true, owner: "root", group: "root"
      node.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", disabled: true

      # setup the hosts, dns and ansible keys
      node.vm.provision "setup-hosts", :type => "shell", :path => "vagrant/setup-hosts.sh" do |s|
        s.args = ["enp0s8"]
      end
      node.vm.provision "setup-dns", type: "shell", :path => "vagrant/update-dns.sh"
      node.vm.provision "shell" do |s|
        ssh_pub_key = File.readlines("#{Dir.home}/.ssh/ansible.pub").first.strip
        s.inline = <<-SHELL
          echo #{ssh_pub_key} >> /home/vagrant/.ssh/authorized_keys
          echo #{ssh_pub_key} >> /root/.ssh/authorized_keys
        SHELL
      end
    end
  end

  # Provision Worker Nodes
  (1..NUM_WORKER_NODE).each do |i|
    config.vm.define "kubenode0#{i}" do |node|
      node.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
          vb.name = "kubenode0#{i}"
          vb.memory = 2048
          vb.cpus = 2
      end
      node.vm.hostname = "kubenode0#{i}"
      node.vm.network :private_network, ip: PRIV_IP_NW + "#{NODE_IP_START + i}"
      node.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 22, host: "#{2711 + i}"

      # synced folder for kubernetes setup yaml
      node.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", disabled: true

      # setup the hosts, dns and ansible keys
      node.vm.provision "setup-hosts", :type => "shell", :path => "vagrant/setup-hosts.sh" do |s|
        s.args = ["enp0s8"]
      end
      node.vm.provision "setup-dns", type: "shell", :path => "vagrant/update-dns.sh"
      node.vm.provision "shell" do |s|
        ssh_pub_key = File.readlines("#{Dir.home}/.ssh/ansible.pub").first.strip
        s.inline = <<-SHELL
          echo #{ssh_pub_key} >> /home/vagrant/.ssh/authorized_keys
          echo #{ssh_pub_key} >> /root/.ssh/authorized_keys
        SHELL
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: share your inventory

Comment: Does vagrant make the SSH ports of the VMs available on localhost? Because you can connect to `vagrant@localhost:271{1,2,3}`. (1) What happens, if you change `ansible_host` to `localhost` (instead of IP addresses)? (2) Can you connect to all VMs by using the IP with the port as in your inventory?

Comment: @phanaz yeah if I set the ansible hosts to localhost it will ping all the endpoints, its just when they are ip addresses and only 1 works that has me trying to understand why

Comment: @Dreamystify What's your Vagrant provider? Virtual Box? Add your Vagrantfile by [editing your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73500827/edit), please.

Comment: @phanaz I added the vagrant file

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because, from the tag: GENERAL VAGRANT SUPPORT IS OFF-TOPIC. Support questions may be asked on https://superuser.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Vagrantfile confirms what I suspected:

1. You define port forwarding as follows:

   ```rb
   node.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 22, host: "#{2710 + i}"
   ```

   That means, port `22` of the guest is made reachable on the host under port `2710+i`. For your 3 VMs, from the host's point of view, this means:

   - `192.168.2.1:22 -> localhost:2711`
   - `192.168.2.2:22 -> localhost:2712`
   - `192.168.2.3:22 -> localhost:2713`
2. As IP addresses for your VMs you have defined the range `192.168.2.0/24`, but you try to access the range `192.168.56.0/24`.
3. If a Private IP address is defined (for your 1st node e.g. `192.168.2.2`), Vagrant implements this in the VM on VirtualBox as follows:
   Two network adapters are defined for the VM:

   1. NAT: this gives the VM Internet access
   2. Host-Only: this gives the host access to the VM via IP `192.168.2.2`.

   For each `/24` network, VirtualBox (and Vagrant) creates a separate `VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter`, and the host is `.1` on each of these networks.

   What this means for you is that if you use an IP address from the `192.168.2.0/24` network, an adapter is created on your host that always gets the IP address `192.168.2.1/24`, so you have the addresses `192.168.2.2` - `192.168.2.254` available for your VMs.

   This means: You have for your master a collision of the IP address with your host!
4. But why does the access to your first VM work?

   ```
   ssh vagrant@192.168.56.1 -p 2711 -i ~/.ssh/ansible <-- successful connection
   ```

   That is relatively simple: The network `192.168.56.0/24` is the default network for Host-Only under VirtualBox, so you probably have a *VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter* with the address `192.168.56.1/24`.

   Because you have defined a port forwarding in your Vagrantfile a mapping of the 1st VM to `localhost:2711` takes place. If you now access `192.168.56.1:2711`, this is your own host, thus `localhost`, and the SSH of the 1st VM is mapped to port `2711` on this host.

#### So what do you have to do now?

1. Change the IP addresses of your VMs, e.g. use `192.168.2.11` - `192.168.2.13`.
2. The access to the VMs is possible as follows:

   | Node | via Guest-IP | via localhost |
   | --- | --- | --- |
   | `kubemaster` | `192.168.2.11:22` | `localhost:2711` |
   | `kubenode01` | `192.168.2.12:22` | `localhost:2712` |
   | `kubenode02` | `192.168.2.13:22` | `localhost:2713` |

   Note: If you want to access with the guest IP address, use port `22`, if you want to access via `localhost`, use port `2710+i` defined by you.

Comment: Using port 22 for accessing when using the ip addresses is what I needed, Thank you for pointing all that out, very helpful!